# 8 bit adder subtractor gives a syntax error

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make a generic 8 bit adder subtractor and I wrote all the code bit it gives me an syntax error on Line "big_mode <= (others => mode);".. any help?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
ENTITY AdderSubtractor IS
GENERIC(n: NATURAL :=8);
    PORT ( Number1 : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
Number2 : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
Mode : IN STD_LOGIC;
Sum : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
Carry : OUT  STD_LOGIC);
END AdderSubtractor;
 ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF AdderSubtractor IS
SIGNAL Tmp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL big_mode: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
zeros<=(others=>'0');
big_mode <= (others => mode);  
tmp<=('0' & Number1 + (('0' & Number2) xor big_mode)+mode);
Sum <= Tmp(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
Carry <= Tmp(n);
END Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zeros` isn't declared in your example code.  On the line before the one you claim has a syntax error (and doesn't apparently).

Commenting  out

```
-- zeros<=(others=>'0');
```

And your code analyzes.

You likely can comment out:

```
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

You're not using any declarations from it (so far).

You could also be using package numeric_std_unsigned instead of the Synopsys packages.

What VHDL tool are you using? (You didn't show us the exact wording of your syntax error).